# regular expression php(regex)

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable that contains multiple date in a format (01AUG) may be any other date.

Now I need to split the variable using the date format given above.This variable contains multiple such format with different dates.Please tell me how i can split this string by date using php.I think regex is only the way we can solve this problem.

```
$var= '01AUG 14:35:27 4026208273880857 521314795212 795212 400088 0200 010000 901 02 14 5,000.00 NPR 0.00 CA ID: 0178SBLN 1001013 22/Kakarvitta /NP 0000 FPI: 886 DG CD: NA ACI: N FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM DECLINE 0.300000CR 04 01AUG 11:42:01 4117733926341924 521311789579 789579 411773 0200 012000 901 02 00 10,400.00 NPR 101.79CR CA ID: 0182SBLN 1001010 25/Lazimpat /NP 0000 FPI: 885 TR ID: 465213429879918 ACI: E SCHG: 400.00 FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -U.S.A. FEE LEVEL: ATM-TIER II AF 0.646805CR 37 02AUG 03:48:19 4539796662883201 521403809409 809409 400088 0200 010000 901 02 05 6,000.00 NPR 0.00 CA ID: 0471SBLN 1001010 25/Thamel Lounge /NP 0000 FPI: 886 DG CD: NA ACI: N FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM DECLINE 0.300000CR 07 01AUG 12:52:12 4547030014539661 521312792592 792592 400088 0200 013000 901 02 57 25,000.00 NPR 0.00 CA ID: 0173SBLN 1001028 25/Boudha /NP 0000 FPI: 886 DG CD: NA ACI: N FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM DECLINE 0.300000CR 07 01AUG 12:57:37 4571652018388487 521312792812 792812 400088 0200 012000 901 02 00 25,000.00 NPR 244.68CR CA ID: 0173SBLN 1001028 25/Boudha /NP 0000 FPI: 886 TR ID: 385213475230796 ACI: E VC: P6RC FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM-TIER II 1.500000CR 08 01AUG 13:20:50 4580030725494543 521313793593 793593 400088 0200 010000 901 02 00 10,000.00 NPR 97.87CR CA ID: 0471SBLN 1001010 25/Thamel Lounge /NP 0000 FPI: 886 TR ID: 305213489171412 ACI: E VC: V7QR FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM-TIER II 1.500000CR 46 02AUG 08:37:38 4595000092328247 521408828378 828378 400088 0200 012000 901 02 00 1,000.00 NPR 9.79CR CA ID: 0171SBLN 1001010 25/Roadhouse Thamel /NP 0000 FPI: 886 TR ID: 385214319247297 ACI: E VC: ZC5V FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM-TIER II 1.500000CR 07 01AUG 12:50:09 4599228000108437 521312792507 792507 400088 0200 012000 901 02 00 10,000.00 NPR 97.87CR CA ID: 0471SBLN 1001010 25/Thamel Lounge /NP 0000 FPI: 886 TR ID: 585213470757658 ACI: E VC: 2V7Z FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM-TIER II 1.500000CR 05 01AUG 12:10:26 4751170038590711 521312790835 790835 400088 0200 010000 901 02 05 6,000.00 NPR 0.00 CA ID: 0300SBLN 1001043 25/Baniyatar /NP 0000 FPI: 886 DG CD: NA ACI: N FEE JURIS: VISA INTERNATIONAL ROUTING: 1 A.P. -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM DECLINE 0.300000CR';
```

I have used preg_split using this pattern

```
preg_match_all('/.+?\s*(?=\b\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\b\s|$)/', $var, $match);
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($match[0]);
       echo '</pre>';
```

Please help me with this.Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: That's why we have preg_match_all .`preg_match_all('/\b(\d\d)(A-Z){3}\b/', $v,$match);`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks Avinash Raj .But I tried this but it gives array within array why is this please try it on ur side and return to me if u could grab result

Comment: i need array like                                                             $array[0]=>01AUG 14:35:27 4026208273880857 521314795212 795212 400088 0200 010000 901 02 14 5,000.00 NPR 0.00 -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM DECLINE 0.300000CR 04;                       array[1]=>05JAN 11:42:01 4117733926341924 521311789579 789579 411773 0200 012000 901 02 00 10,400.00 NPR 101.79CR I 0.646805CR 37

Comment: it's beacuse of capturing groups. remove that, `preg_match_all('/\b\d\d(?:A-Z){3}\b/', $v,$match);`

Comment: Sorry but ,I tried your code in online regex tester but output was   a empty array

Comment: You write: *I have used preg_split...* but sample shows `preg_match_all`. With `preg_split` you want to split at `\s+` if followed by `\b\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\s` so the split pattern with lookahead would be like this: `\s+(?=\b\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\s)` See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sQ3yO8/1) and [eval.in](https://eval.in/414178)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
preg_match_all('/.+?\s*(?=\b\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\b\s|$)/', $var, $match);

// check output
print_r($match[0]);
Array
(
    [0] => 01AUG 14:35:27 4026208273880857 521314795212 795212 400088 0200 010000 901 02 14 5,000.00 NPR 0.00 -E.U. FEE LEVEL: ATM DECLINE 0.300000CR 04
    [1] => 05JAN 11:42:01 4117733926341924 521311789579 789579 411773 0200 012000 901 02 00 10,400.00 NPR 101.79CR I 0.646805CR 37
    [2] => 02AUG 03:48:19 4539796662883201 521403809409 809409 400088 0200
)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV1zR0/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
.+?                        # match 1 or more of any character (non-greedy)
\s*                        # match 0 or more spaces
(?=...)                    # a positive lookahead
(?=\b\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\b\s|$)  # match must be followed by a word boundary + 2 digits +
                           # 3 uppercase letters + word boundary OR line end
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava, your solution almost worked in live regex but in my code this array is shown when I copy your code                        Array ( [0] => 04 [1] => 37 [2] => 07 [3] => 07 [4] => 08 [5] => 46 [6] => 07 [7] => 05 [8] => ).


) What's the problem please explain

Comment: Can you show your code by editing your question OR else show the input data you're using.

Comment: Yes,I have added the input string and code I am using

Comment: Why is my browser not showing the data I deserve and how can i make this array to my required array as you showed above??

Comment: It could be due to your css/js etc. I suggest you test without browser first on command line or in IDE. Once verified then test in a plain HTML file without including any css/js.

Comment: No..It has still the same problem.When I assign the static value to variable   then it works but same value when it is dynamic doesnot give the required array.Can you define same in preg_split then it would be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86573/discussion-between-sagar-chapagain-and-anubhava).

Comment: I am at work so can't chat for now. But you can use: `$arr = preg_split('/(?=\b\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\b)/', $var, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` also.